# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders Laravel 8 upsert

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, placeholder, upsert

Getting error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too
> many placeholders...

while upsert large data.

Here is my code:

```
$reportItem = ReportItem::upsert($data->toArray(), ['someId','otherId']);
```

I think this limit because of mysql and i tried to use chunk but no success. Any help?

```
$reportItem = ReportItem::chunk(1000, upsert($data->toArray(), ['someId','otherId']));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk) the "$data" collection to be inserted.

```
foreach ($data->chunk(100) as $chunk) {
    ReportItem::upsert($chunk->toArray(), ['someId','otherId']);
}
```